# MSBuild delete generated UIds

Tags: c#, msbuild, locbaml

After I generated the Uid's with the following command:

```
msbuild /t:updateuid MyProject.csproj
```

How can I delete them all.

I know how I can check the generated Uid's like this but I want to really delete them:

```
msbuild /t:checkuid Myproject.csproj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
msbuild /t:removeuid MyProject.csproj
```